# Embed .swf in webpage and make it fullscreen

Tags: flash, embed, fullscreen, adobe-captivate

Is there a way to embed a .swf file in a webpage and provide a way to make it fullscreen?
I'm creating these files with Adobe Captivate, which doesn't seem to provide a way to publish in other usable formats (.avi files are too big, and no .flv is available, to which there seem to have some players around that allow fullscreen).

If there's a way to convert .swf to some other "embedable" format, please let me know.

Comment: check this link from adobe
https://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS44B1892B-1668-4a80-8431-6BA0F1947766.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not make a link to the swf in question without a HTML file embedding it. This way the swl will fill the whole browser screen.

Comment: That is the backup solution, if I can't find a way to do what I described.

Comment: And it's also what I ended up doing. Thanks.

Comment: That actually only works in Firefox. In Chrome, however, the file gets downloaded and IE 8 shows content of SWF file as text.

Answer (score 2):

You can create full screen swfs easily with html and javascript (that's the only way).

See [Creating Full Screen Flex Applications](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/08/07/creating-full-screen-flex-applications/).

Basically, you just add a parameter to the `embed` or `object` tag: `allowScriptAccess:true`.  And the only thing you need in your swf other than your video is to set `stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;`.  Not sure if you can do that without writing any actionscript.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fullscreen widget for Captivate here:
http://www.m-gd.com/en/playbar-fullscreen-captivate-widget/
It inserts a button just as in YouTube, so that you can toggle to fullscreen.
In addition there is a virtual keyboard, because you cannot enter text into text input fields.