# Is it possible to make an swf object fullscreen with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flash, fullscreen

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flash to take the view to fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706317/flash-to-take-the-view-to-fullscreen)

So is it possible to make a flash game fullscreen when a button is pressed using jquery ?
and if this can't be done what are the alternatives if I don't want to use html5 fullscreen ?

update: Full browser is ok it doesn't have to be fullscreen

Comment: jquery or no, javascript can not fullscreen a swf.   Similar question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2272554/embed-swf-in-webpage-and-make-it-fullscreen

Comment: However, if you have control over the swf file, you could implement dom level functions that can call into flash-land and trigger fullscreen from there with externalinterface.